# which query consumes less resources an update or a select

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I need to do an update under certain circumstances in SQL.
It is an update of a single element in a table.
Which of these options will consume more resources.

1. Ask first if the update would be necessary by means of a select and then do the update or
2. execute the query so that the update is carried out despite the fact that in some cases it will overwrite the same values.

Comment: How often do you expect to have to perform an `UPDATE` after a `SELECT`? Have you profiled your statements to see the logical and time costs of each approach? More broadly, why are you asking? Has profiling highlighted this as a bottleneck for your system? It sounds like you may be [prematurely optimizing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- More queries --> more time taken.
- `UPDATE` is slower than `SELECT`, but faster than `SELECT+UPDATE`.
- If the purpose of the `SELECT` is to see if the `UPDATE` is needed, simply doing the `UPDATE` by itself is probably better.
- IODKU (upsert) is a single query that checks for the existence of a row, then either inserts a new row or updates the existing row.  (Uses `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key to determine new vs existing.)
- A single query is "atomic".  But a `SELECT` plus an `UPDATE` may need these *four* commands to avoid "race conditions":

  ```
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT ...   FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE  ...;
    COMMIT;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

there is a time gap in your option 1.
it is theoretically possible to select to find no issue - then someone else does an update - then you do an update thinking it is safe..

option 2 does not have this issue.

Comment: You're correct, but note that [MySQL supports transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) and [transaction isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a third option: do an update selectively.

For example, let's say you want to reduce a balance by an amount, but only if the balance is greater than the amount.

You could create a query like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET balance = balance - :amount 
   WHERE accountID = :accountId AND balance >= :amount
```

Then check ROW_COUNT() to see if the update succeeded. (PHP and other languages have specific functions for this)

This has the specific benefit that it avoids the race condition implicit in the SELECT - UPDATE approach.

Comment: It's something like "rows_affected".